# What is the meaning of invoke all function in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

Basically i want to know the the following function in taxonomy module.

```
module_invoke_all('taxonomy', $hook, 'term', $form_values);

$hook="insert";
```

What does this function  do ?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The function `module_invoke_all` checks all active modules and tries to find implementations of the *taxonomy* hook (in your case). In other words: are there any functions named MODULENAME_taxonomy?
If found, *all* these functions are called. 
In your example, these calls look like

`MODULENAME_taxonomy('insert', 'term', $form_values)`.

This way, other modules can interfere when a new taxonomy term is inserted.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/6 .